# Creating collections of posts with Rails 5 (as in Pinterest Boards)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, collections, ruby-on-rails-5, grouping, bucket

I have over 500 posts and growing rapidly. I want to give a feature for users to create collections [title, description, posts] and assign posts to them. 1 post can belong to many collections from different users.

**Example:**

- User A creates a collection named "DARK DESIGNS"
- User A clicks "add to collection" button in post/show page and selects her own "Dark Design" collection
- User A goes into another post and assigns more posts into "Dark Design"
- User A sees list of her collections at her profile

**Question:**

How should I structure this collections feature? Should I just do **scaffold collections**? How should I hold post ids in database, just in a field separated with commas?

Thank you

---

I need users to be able to create collections and assign 1 post to multiple collections.

Should my database structure be like:

### Existing tables

table [posts]

- id
- title
- image
- many more fields

---

table [users]

- id
- username
- many more fields

---

### New tables

table [collections]

- id
- title
- desc
- user_id

---

table [collections_posts]

- id
- post_id
- collection_id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you need a separate `Collection` model with `title` and `description` fields, and additional CollectionsPost model for `has_many` association.

```
class CollectionsPost < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :collection
  belongs_to :post
end
class Collection < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :collections_posts
  has_many :posts, through: :collections_posts
end
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :collections_posts
  has_many :collections, through: :collections_posts
end
```

And maybe Collection should belong to User, if you want to display list of users collections on the profile page.

Comment: ah ok, so I should not have any user_id in collections or collection_id in posts table. Instead, I should have a separate CollectionsPosts table with collection_id and post_id fields. So I probably need one more separate table for CollectionsUsers. 

Comment: Or actually I guess I can add user_id (Devise) to Collections table, right? After all, every collection belongs to an user.

Comment: @Designer, I see your question update, but I can't comment below the question (not enough reputation). Yes, you are right about models structure

Comment: Thanks for the direction, I found some detailed tutorials for **has_many :through** that does what I need

Comment: @Designer, not at all :)